# Web scraping using a url-list in R

Tags: r, url, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape some URLs from multiple websites I collected. I saved the already collected websites in a dataframe called `meetings2017_2018`. The problem is that URLs don't look very similar to one another except the first part of the URLs: `https://amsterdam.raadsinformatie.nl`. The second part of urls are saved in the dataframe. Here are some examples:

`/vergadering/458873/raadscommissie%20Algemene%20Zaken
 /vergadering/458888/raadscommissie%20Wonen
 /vergadering/458866/raadscommissie%20Jeugd%20en%20Cultuur
 /vergadering/346691/raadscommissie%20Algemene%20Zaken`

So the whole URL would be `https://amsterdam.raadsinformatie.nl/vergadering/458873/raadscommissie%20Algemene%20Zaken`

I managed to create a very simple function from which I can pull out the URLs from a single website (see below).

```
web_scrape <- function(meeting) {
      url <-  glue("https://amsterdam.raadsinformatie.nl{meeting}")
      read_html(url) %>%
      html_nodes("a") %>%
      html_attr("href")
      }
```

With this function I still need to insert every single URL from the dataframe I want to scrape. Since there more than 140 in the dataframe this might take a while. As you can guess, I want to scrape all the urls at once using the url-list in the dataframe. Does anybody know how I can do that?

Comment: Hi! You can map/iterate over all of your URL you saved in the `meetings2017_2018` data frame. Do you know how to do this or do you want to have some guidance?

Comment: and... Do I understand this correctly: I gather many URLs with your function `web_scrape`. And afterwards you want to go to every of these URLs and extract some information from it, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. I wrote a simple filter code for the URLs that are gathered once the function works properly, but I thought for this question it was not relevant. I am not sure how to map/iterate. I tried using the map function in this way `map(meetings2017_2018, web_scrape)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map/iterate over your saved URL in the `meetings2017_2018` data frame:

Assuming your URLs are saved in a `url` column in your `meetings2017_2018` data frame a starting point would be:

```
# create a vector of the URLs
urls <- pull(meetings2017_2018, url)

# map over the URLs and execute whatever code you want for every URL
map(urls, function(url) {
    your_code
})
```

Comment: I tried the following, but I got a error messages saying `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 400.`   `urls <- pull(meetings2017_2018, urls)

map(urls, function(url) {
  url <-  glue("https://amsterdam.raadsinformatie.nl{url}")
  read_html(url) %>%
    html_nodes("a") %>%
    html_attr("href")
    })`

Comment: it worked. There were some white spaces in the URLs, which was the reason that I got an error message. Thanks for your help! Only thing I have to do now is unnest the dataframe

Comment: I do have another question. I thought it would be easy to unnest/unlist the output, but seems I am stuck here too. The output is a large list with 145 elements (for each website that was scraped). Every element has different number of rows (between 90-300), but all have one column called X[[i]]. Do you know I can make it one big data frame with two columns: (1) the number of the element and (2) the row information?

Comment: You should make a minimal reproducible example and post a new question.